Interact with Deployed Contract
Can we interact with a deployed contract without web3 library meaning through another contract. Can we make a call to another contract inside of a contract through may be assembly keyword that makes low level calls to evm may be I thought that could happen. At the end everything stored on the nodes that uses evm. Is that possible?

Yes you can do that. There is a call opcode:
OPCODE : 0xF1   
Name   : CALL   
Gas    : AA (will depend on the call)
Stack  : Gas to pass with the call, 
         Address to call on, 
         Value of native coin to pass, 
         Offset in memory of calldata to send, 
         Lengh in bytes of calldata,
         Offset in memory to store returned data,
         Length of returned data to store.

//-----------------------------------------------

assembly {
  call(Gas, Address, Value, argOffset, argLength, retOffset, retLength)
}

You shouldn't need to use low level raw calls in the vast majority of cases.
Can instead define the interface for the external function you are calling, inside your contract file. It just needs to conform enough to encode the calldata accurately.
A simple way to do this is search for the function you want to call in the external contract, then copy and paste the function minus its body (anything between the curly braces).
You'll be left with the signature (the name of the function and the types of the arguments), which you can include in an interface as follows:
interface IERC20 {
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
}

Then within your contract body you can wrap an address with the interface and call the method.
contract Approver {
  address token = 0xaB1a4d4f1D656d2450692D237fdD6C7f9146e814;
  address router = 0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3;
  function approve() public {
    IERC20(token).approve(router, 1e18);
  }
}

